# ruby splat operator compilation error in eclipse but runs fine on command line

Tags: ruby, eclipse, variadic-functions, splat, dltk

I have the following ruby script **ruby_test.rb** in eclipse (DLTK/RUBY), which throws a compilation error and I am not able to run in eclipse. This makes sense since **arr* should be the last parameter. But when I run it on command line (***ruby ruby_test.rb***) its runs fine. any idea why?

My installed ruby version is 2.1.6p336

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

arr = [1,2,3]

def test(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5)
   puts "The first number  is #{a1}"
   puts "The second number is #{a2}"
end

test(0, *arr, 4)
```

Comment: Different interpreters, probably. The official Ruby one allows things like this IIRC

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you have an old version of Ruby on eclipse, on which a splat argument had to be the last argument.

Comment: I am using "/Users/north/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.6/bin/ruby" as the interpreter executable as ruby interpreter in eclipse preferences. Any other setting I may be missing?

Comment: I confirmed that by writing a 1 line script with ` puts RUBY_VERSION ` which results in output 2.1.6

Comment: There  surely is something wrong or outdated with your eclipse setting.